# How to find ip address in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ip-address

I am using a following function to track the user's ip address. I run the application on localhost.

```
    $this->input->ip_address();
```

when I try to execute this function on my computer's localhost it returns ::1 and same thing I tryied on another computer it returns same ip address. my confusion is why it not showing the diffrent ip address for that two diffrent computers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`::1` is the loopback address in IPv6. Which is same as `127.0.0.1.` That is `localhost`.

The code is correct. Which return the ip address. You can see different IP when running this code on server.

```
$ip = $this->input->ip_address();
```

Comment: Do you mean when I upload the site on server, so it gives the diffrent ip address for diffrent machine as I expect?

Comment: Yes. ::1 is the ip address of localhost. Now you are giving request only from localhost. So that you get the localhost ip address